# Get Current Frame in iOS Animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview, core-animation

Here's my code:

```
-(void)play {
    animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"contents"];
    for (UIImage *image in folder.images) {
        [images addObject:(id)image.CGImage];
    }
    animationArray = [images subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(selected, selectedEnd - selected)];
    timeBetweenAnimation = 1.0/framesPerSecond;
    totalAnimationTime = folder.images.count * timeBetweenAnimation;
    animation.duration = totalAnimationTime;
    animation.values = animationArray;
    animation.delegate = self;
    beforeAdd = CACurrentMediaTime();
    [displayImage.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"contents"];
    afterAdd = CACurrentMediaTime();
}

-(void)animationDidStart {
    afterStart = CACurrentMediaTime();
}
```

I am using Core Animation to animate an array of images and I want to get the current image in the animation when I pause the image.  I realize that a method of doing this would be to get the image from "animationArray" using timing ratios (played time / total duration time), but I can't capture the begin time.  I've tried capturing the begin time, using CACurrentMediaTime(), before and after the call to addAnimation:forKey: and also after animation did start, but it's innaccurate (especially when I have a large array of images).  With a larger array of images, the "beforeAdd" and "afterAdd" times are at least a second off.  Also, "afterStart" is anywhere between .04 and .08 seconds off independent of the size of my images array.

In the worst case scenario, I could use the "afterStart" begin time. However, if I'm trying to animate 100 images in 1 second, getting the image using this method would be inaccurate by 4 frames.  Therefore, I either need a method that doesn't use timing in order to get the current frame of the animation, or I need a way to get a more accurate begin time.  Is this possible?

NOTE:  I don't want to use UIImageView animation to do this because that animation technique doesn't have smooth transitioning between frames.  If there were a way to have smooth transitioning between frames using UIImageView animation I would reconsider, although I'm pretty sure there will still be an issue when calculating the begin time.